# ajax + php yet another suggestion for correct error handling

Tags: php, jquery

The $.ajax has two returns: success and error.
If $.ajax calls a php module, how to dispatch the responses to success and to error ?
For example:
if this line of code returns an error:

```
$connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
```

I would like to receive the error in ajax-error
if the execution of the php module is correct then I would like to receive a message in ajax-sucess
If I send echo "message" from PHP I receive the message always in ajax-success and I am obliged to test what is a success and what is not !

Comment: On failure, don't echo.... Use trigger_error.

Comment: you mean, with echo, the callback will be success, with trigger_error, the callback will be error ?

Comment: given you a working answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [jQuery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> *error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)*
>   A function to be called **if the request fails**. ...

On server-side the request has already succeed. Normally the resulting callback will be the success handler, not the error handler.

You should handle the mysql_connect error in the ajax-success handler.

Comment: you can trigger an error and send the status as error which will trigger the ajax error function. e.g. In yii, just throw a CHttpException in the server side and the ajax error kicks in. So "So the resulting callback will ever be the success handler, never the error callback." is a misconception. You need to just create a custom error handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the ajax error callback will return error only if the *ajax* call does not work, not if something(like a sql command in your case), in your (successfully 'ajaxed') *script* does not work.

However, to handle the sql error from the data in your ajax success callback function, you could maybe parse the returned data.  What I mean is that you can create a div with id='sql_error' in your script output, then read the content of this div. If there was no sql error then your error div must have zero content.

Something like this, maybe (untested):

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    var sql_error = $("#sql_error", data).html(); 
    // or var content = $("#error", $(data)).html();

    // you can then show output in the way you want, depending on sql_error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.... (tested). Use this in the conditional for errors in the server side.

```
header('403 Forbidden', true, 403);
die('forbiden to log in. No authorization');
```

This will evoke the error function. Put the status code and message according to your need.